# OpenCV debug install through Homebrew

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I would like to to build and install OpenCV in debug mode on my Mac.  I prefer do do this in  Homebrew since Homebrew manages everything else in my /usr/local and is able to properly uninstall.

I have edited the Homebrew formula to add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG` to the cmake command-line.

But the main challenge now is to keep the source around after the build, or perhaps, copy the source first to a permanent location and do the build from there.  I believe this is necessary to be able step into OpenCV in Xcode debugger.

Is there a simple way to do this in Homebrew?  If not, are there any examples of custom formulas that do this sort of thing?  I'm not very familiar with Ruby so any sample code would be helpful.